# 500.19 - Internal Server Error ISS website

Tags: asp.net, iis, web

I tried creating new web applications...

I have been using VS 2010 for developing website

I make use of wsp builder to package all my dlls, pages, scripts and images into a solution package and deploy it in the web applications.

I am trying to get a MVC Web App running in my IIS. Unfortunately, I am absolutely stuck on this error:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The Request page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for 
the page is invalid.

```
Module: IIS Web Core
Notification: Unknown
Handler: Not yet determined
Error Code: 0x80070005
Config Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
Config File: \\?\C:\Users\dev.fuji\Desktop\Mywebiste\web.config
Request URL: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Logon Method: Not yet determined
Logon User: Not yet determined

Config Source
-1:
0:
```

I am not quite sure what else to do. Why I got this error, I search even youtube but everyone get it worked but why not me.. I do almost exactly they done.

MAYBE** because before this the server already done by someone else in my place... I new worker in my it department...so I miss the installment part in video.. Is that what make the error? Do I have to reinstall my iis??

If anyone has any information or would be able to help me work through this it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This could be permission issue. first you host your website from *wwwroot* (this folder contains all required access by default) folder in iis.

Comment: thanks i get it done... it worked now some of error 

Line 12:  </connectionStrings>
Line 13:  <system.web>
Line 14:   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
Line 15:   <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 16:    <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config file shouldn't be located on the dev desktop.. it should be within your website, and that website should be located somewhere within IIS (default location is c:\inetput\wwwroot\).  Start there, if you have any questions, I'd say give this URL a shot first: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/create-a-web-site

Comment: Wow i think i almost there!!! it worked but i have some of error...

Line 12:  </connectionStrings>
Line 13:  <system.web>
Line 14:   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
Line 15:   <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 16:    <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>

Comment: IT WOKRED , i change the folder to the default location and  apppool to asp.net 4.0 and it worked!!! my god thanks alot man!